# pointing domain name to java application in VPS

Tags: java, tomcat, hosting, vps

I have purchased a VPS hosting. Installed java 1.7 and Tomcat 7. I have deployed war file in tomcat, its working fine in local host; I'm getting the desired output. I have purchased hosting space too. A directory is created (e.g: mywebsite.com) where if I put some static index.html page and access the site as http://www.mywebsite.com it's working fine, i.e, index.html is displayed. My problem is instead of displaying that index.html, upon typing of that web address my java application need to be invoked. How can I do this? Please guide me

Comment: Hey man did you ever figure this out. It sounds like you were trying to have some apps run on tomcat while other apps were running on a typical apache server. I have some sites running in www/folder on centOS and I want to point other incoming URLs to the tomcat/webapps/newJavaSite so I can deploy a jsp app. How did you end up doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do 2 things

1) In tomcat conf/server.xml file modift  tag entry as

```
<Host name="mywebsite.com"  appBase="d:/webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
```

d:/webapps --> inside this folder you should have your web application or war file.

2) In your web application, you need to add welcome file list tag in web.xml as

```
<welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>pages/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: i have done with the same. but i cant change the default.aspx if i remove it i will get an error.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you map, your domains www record to you vps  IP address.

You can do it by logging into your domain control panel

There is no need of hosting space as you already have a VPS

Comment: k if i map the domains too how can i point to war file running in tomcat?

Comment: configure to start your tomcat in 80 port(conf/web.xml) , clear everything from webapps dir, copy your war file and rename it as ROOT.war then start tomcat, you can access your app at http://yourip, now you map your wwww A record to yourip

Comment: k brother, but can i access it directly by typing www.mywebsite.com?

Comment: probably you purchased mywebsite.com from a provider like godaddy, enom etc, you need to login to the providers website using provided credentials(you will have a password/username) then you can access their control panel, and set A record for www, then you will be able to access www.mywebsite.com. Effectively you are configuring the dns server , so that when a request comes to www.mywebsite.com  , it is resolved to your vps IP

Comment: you should wait for some time may be hours so that your record , is propogated

Comment: probably yes, when i login to website panel there i can create any number of domains, i have created mywebsite.com where a folder by name mywebsite.com is created in c:/ drvie of VPS server in that a a folder wwwroot is present which contains default.aspx page. but i want that web address to be redirected to my war file? how can i do that from the default.aspx?

Comment: May be reverse proxy is also something which can help you http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy

Answer (score -1):

You can simply update domain configuration to forward any request to yourwebsite.com to VPS server address like http:// ipaddress:port /myAPP